# Resize image to parent div

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image with a `600px` width.

It needs to be inside a bootstrap `col-xs-6` or `12` div with a width of `300px` and has to be resized if the screen width is smaller than `300px`.

How can I realize that using `width` and `max-width` in CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just do this:

```
img { 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 300px; 
  height: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

If the div width is bigger than 300px image will have maximum width of 300px. If div is smaller than 300px image should fill 100% width of div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.my-image {
    max-width:300px;
    width:100%;
}
```

These rules basically mean, display the image at the full width of its container *unless* the container is larger than 300px, in which case, limit the image to 300px.